# How to reset the value of the cookie in javascript in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have to set the value of the LoginId textbox from the value in the cookie 'UserLoginId'
then once I assign it to the textbox I have to set the value of the cookie to blank(or "").
 I am not getting how to reset the value to " ".

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
    var jcookie = '@HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["UserLoginId"].Value';   
    $("#LogInId").val(jcookie);
// What to write here to set the value of "UserLoginId"=""?
</script>
```

Please help me with this..

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove it, you should change expiration date:

```
document.cookie = name + '=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;';
```

Answer (score 0):

In the place of  //What to writ here..

```
document.cookie = "userLoginId="+escape("");
```